# JQuery append image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For this code block

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $("#main").append(factory());
    }
  });
```

this will show the image:

```
function factory() {
    return $('<image class="champ-icon rounded-circle" src="resources/irelia.jpg" />');
}
```

[image]

while this doesn't

```
function factory() {
    let $champIcon = $(document.createElement("image"))
      .addClass("champ-icon rounded-circle")
      .attr("src", "resources/irelia.jpg");
    return $champIcon;
}
```

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap 4 as well.

The page currently is just a static mock up. I want to dynamically build elements from data given to it by a local server.

I literally just messed around with HTML/CSS and jQuery over the weekend so I'm not sure what went wrong here. Shouldn't both function return the same jQuery object?

Thanks!

CSS class

```
.champ-icon {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
```

**Edit**: creating it with normal javascript works as well.

```
function factory() {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = "resources/irelia.jpg";
        img.className = "champ-icon rounded-circle";
        return img;
```

Comment: The correct HTML tag is `img` not `image`.  Try `document.createElement("img")`

Comment: replace .$(document.createElement("image")) with $(document.createElement("img"))

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to programmatically create `<image>` element in html, which... doesn't exist. To insert element on a page you should use `<img src="">`, not `<image...>`. Change this line

```
let $champIcon = $(document.createElement("image"))
```

to

```
let $champIcon = $(document.createElement("img"))
```

And it should work.

Comment: or `let $champIcon = $('<img>')`

Comment: YES. i just realized there's img and image. XD. thanks

Comment: If I managed to help, can you kindly mark my answer as accepted? Thanks a lot and have a good day (or night ;))